# Is there a GPU/parallelized python implementation of k-NN which does not rebuild the KDTree upon the addition or subtraction of one point?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencl, knn, point-clouds

I have a dynamic point cloud in 3D, and I would like to use nanoflann to dynamically add/subtract points in between queries, without rebuilding the tree (as seen here):

https://github.com/jlblancoc/nanoflann/blob/master/examples/dynamic_pointcloud_example.cpp

I have found a python wrapper for nanoflann as well (awesome!):

https://github.com/u1234x1234/pynanoflann

This is great! However, speed is extremely important for my application so I will almost certainly need to parallelize this k-NN implementation. Is there an existing python implementation or wrapper for such a dynamic k-NN implementation written with OpenCL or CUDA? I wanted to check if one exists before writing my own. This "dynamic" is different than wanting to be able to specify a new k with each query. I don't mind if it is a single KDTree with a set k. I simply need to be able to remove or add points in between queries without rebuilding the KDTree.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What algorithm would you use, to do so without rebuilding the tree or optimise this ?

Comment: Is this the implementation example you are looking for https://github.com/artifabrian/dynamic-knn-gpu